# change post to "custom post type" without changing the the URL

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

This question has been asked before but I couldnt find an answer for my situation.

I have some existing posts which needs to be changed to a new CPT . 
when I change to the new CPT , the url is also updated. how can I prevent this ?

Also I do want the slug to appear for any new pages that I create in future for the CPT .

```
       $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'label'              => 'Custom Page',
        'description'        => 'Custom Page',
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-smartphone',
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array(
            'slug'       => 'custom',
            'with_front' => false
        ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => false,
        'hierarchical'       => true,
        'menu_position'      => 5,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'page-attributes'),
    );

    register_post_type( 'custom_page', $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a neat plugin [Post Type Switcher](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/).

What this plugin would do is switch any post type to any post type with seconds i think you can always use this plugin and delete this plugin.. give it a try

Comment: It changes the url of the post